# call ajax function when user refreshes or leaves web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call an ajax function when the user leaves a web page or refreshes a web page. So far I can call an ajax function when the user closes the page using javascript `window.onunload = my_ajax_function;` but I also need to call `my_ajax_function` when the page is refreshed or the user leaves the page to go to a different url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A refresh will also trigger `onunload` (and `onbeforeunload`). However, you need to make the call synchronous (`async: false` in the `$.ajax()` options) so it's not aborted due to the page being unloaded.

```
$(window).on('unload', function() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'whatever',
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

in order to call the ajax function on page refresh is to put it in the `ready` handler

```
$(function(){
 //your ajax func
});
```

and to detect the user navigating away from the page use

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    //your code here
}
```